# Xamarin Studio: I can deploy an app but it doesn't start

Tags: deployment, xamarin-studio

[image]I have another strange problem with an iPad. From my iMac with Xamarin Studio, I can deploy an app on the device but I receive an alert:

> Application already installed.

Xamarin Studio can't launch the app on the device. I deployed a lot of time this and other apps on this device. If I try to launch the app, it doesn't start at all. No error or crashes in the device logs.

With other iPads I have no problem.

Comment: Sometimes you need delete the app deplyed through Xamarin. restarted ur ipad. snd then redeploy

Answer (score 0):

Try a different "Debugger port" setting in the "project properties" -> "iOS Debug". The default port is 10000. Try 10001 and others.